# OpenLayers 3: Attributions

Tags: openlayers, duplication, attribution

I have a number of layers which share the same attribution. When more then one of them are visible at the same time I get something like this in my attribution control:

> Company1 hyperlink1 Company2 hyperlink2 Company1 hyperlink1
>   Company1 hyperlink1

How can I avoid duplicates and have only unique records shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to make a single attribution object then re-use that across your layers, e.g.

```
var company1Attribution = new ol.Attribution({ html: 'Company1 hyperlink1'});
```

then in your source object, re-use that variable:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.WMTS({
        url: 'url',
        layer: 'layer1',
        ...
        attributions: [company1Attribution]
    })
})

new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.WMTS({
        url: 'url',
        layer: 'layer2',
        ...
        attributions: [company1Attribution]
    })
})
```

Openlayers should then only show one version of it on the map.